# run specific scripts in specific order using cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a bundle of scripts to run. For my smoke test pack, I need only few scripts containing tests need to be run. And, it has to run in a specific order.

Below are the scripts in Cypress. And, each of these scripts contains multiple tests to run.

```
Create Department
Create Centre
Create Exam Paper
Create Student
Prepare Exam Details
```

I need these scripts to execute in above mentioned order. So that the tests within those scripts gets tested against the intended features. How to set this order of execution in configuration files (cypress.json or package.json) and how to run it from test runner or terminal? Any help on this please.

Comment: These above mentioned names, are these test suite (or spec.js files) ?

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to use `testFiles` to order tests, but annoying if you want several different sequences.

Instead, create a "dummy" test which imports the others and run that

**smoke-in-order.spec.js**

```js
import 'Create-Department.spec.js';
import 'Create-Centre.js';
import 'Create-Exam Paper.js';
import 'Create-Student.js';
import 'Prepare-Exam-Details.js';
```

You can have as many "smoke" variations as you want, no need to change the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the above names are names of the test suite file name. To run them in order, you can do either of the two methods below.

1. Change the file names and add numbers like this:

```js
1-Create-Department.spec.js
2-Create-Centre.spec.js
3-Create-Exam-Paper.spec.js
4-Create-Student.spec.js
5-Prepare-Exam-Details.spec.js
```

2. or, in case you don't want to change the file names, you can add in your `cypress.json` under `testFiles` array in the sequence you like:

```js
testFiles: [
  'Create Department.spec.js',
  'Create Centre.spec.js',
  'Create Exam Paper.spec.js',
  'Create Student.spec.js',
  'Prepare Exam Details.spec.js',
]
```